# Rust wrapper for a C API that expects "uint8_t *pk"

Tags: rust, ffi

I need to use a C library in rust on an LPC55S69 board. Here is the header file for the C library that I need to use in my rust app https://github.com/mupq/pqm4/blob/master/crypto_sign/dilithium2/m4f/api.h.

To start with I am only trying to write a wrapper for one of the API from the header file:

```
int crypto_sign_keypair(uint8_t *pk, uint8_t *sk);
```

Here is how I am trying to use it in rust's main.rs.

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]
pub const PUBLICKEYBYTES: usize = 1312;
pub const SECRETKEYBYTES: usize = 2558;

extern "C" {
    pub fn crypto_sign_keypair(pk: *mut u8, sk: *mut u8) -> cty::c_int;
}

#[cortex_m_rt::entry]
fn main() -> ! {
  let mut public_key: [u8; PUBLICKEYBYTES] = [0u8; PUBLICKEYBYTES];
  let mut secret_key: [u8; SECRETKEYBYTES] = [0u8; SECRETKEYBYTES];
  let res = unsafe { crypto_sign_keypair(public_key.as_mut_ptr(), secret_key.as_mut_ptr()) }; # program stucks on this line forever
}
```

The rust program get stuck forever when I use this C api. I am assuming that it is because of the rust wrapper as this API is working fine in my C application. Following is the sample code how I call in C:

```
#define SECRETKEYBYTES 2558
#define PUBLICKEYBYTES 1312
int main(void) {
  uint8_t sk[SECRETKEYBYTES], pk[PUBLICKEYBYTES];
  crypto_sign_keypair(pk, sk);
}
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong while calling the C API from rust?

Comment: This doesn't compile, please provide a [mre]. Probably wouldn't hurt to see one of the working C version either.

Comment: @cafce25 added more details. Please let me know if I need to add more details.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Are you sure it's not a problem inside of `crypto_sign_keypair`? Please provide a full [mre], without being able to reproduce your problem on our own computers, we can't help you further.

Comment: For example, I see that this is for a microcontroller, maybe you didn't build the C library for the correct platform? And it crashes because it tries to execute x86 assembly or similar? Ok technically that shouldn't even link, but something more trivial? Like an armv7 instruction for an armv6 target?

Comment: Where does `generate_keypair()` come from?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That was a typo. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Finomnis I verified it. I am using thumbv8m.main-none-eabi for LPC55S69. It was crashing in one of the assemply files of the library. I repalced the assembly code with c and seems to work fine now. I'll debug that another time unless its related to FFI?

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible, as you already stated in your answer. An accepted answer that simply states that the problem is not actually in the question doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score -2):

Like @Fnomnis mentioned, the code was already correct. My program was crashing in one of the library's function in assembly. Replacing the assembly functions with C code worked just fine. I updated the rust wrapper code to look like:

```
pub fn sb_crypto_sign_keypair() -> ([u8;PUBLICKEYBYTES as usize], [u8;SECRETKEYBYTES as usize]) {
    let mut pk = [0; PUBLICKEYBYTES as usize];
    let mut sk = [0; SECRETKEYBYTES as usize];
    unsafe {
        crypto_sign_keypair(&mut pk as *mut _, &mut sk as *mut _);
    }
    (pk,sk) 
}

extern "C" {
    pub crypto_sign_keypair(
        pk: *mut u8,
        sk: *mut u8,
    ) -> c_int; }
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions with "the problem is not actually in the question". An accepted answer should contain a solution, so that other people can also solve their similar problems; Stackoverflow is meant as a huge Q&A. If the question is not reproducible/answerable, then it is a reason to close the question instead.

Answer (score -3):

In the Rust Standard Library there is a module called `ffi`. This filled with `c` values. Like what you want uint8_t. Use `*mut std::ffi::c_uint` instead of `*mut u8`. Like this:

```rust
extern "C" {
    pub fn generate_keypair(pk: *mut std::ffi::c_uint, sk: *mut std::ffi::c_uint) -> cty::c_int; // You can get rid of the `cty` in the `cty::c_int`
}
let mut public_key: [u8; PUBLICKEYBYTES] = [0u8; PUBLICKEYBYTES];
let mut secret_key: [u8; SECRETKEYBYTES] = [0u8; SECRETKEYBYTES];
let res = unsafe { generate_keypair(public_key, secret_key) }; # program stucks on this line forever
```

Or you can import it:

```rust
use std::ffi::c_uint;
extern "C" {
    pub fn generate_keypair(pk: *mut c_uint, sk: *mut c_uint) -> c_int; // You can get rid of the `cty` in the `cty::c_int`
}
let mut public_key: [u8; PUBLICKEYBYTES] = [0u8; PUBLICKEYBYTES];
let mut secret_key: [u8; SECRETKEYBYTES] = [0u8; SECRETKEYBYTES];
let res = unsafe { generate_keypair(public_key, secret_key) }; # program stucks on this line forever
```

Comment: As I am working on an embedded device I cannot use `std` package. Any other ideas?

Comment: @tarun14110 Just replace `std::ffi` with [`core::ffi`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ffi/index.html). `core` is available in no-std environments.

Comment: @kmdreko thanks. but I am getting followup errors. I got error `expected *mut u32, found [u8; 1952]`. I fixed it by adding `.as_mut_ptr()` in public_key and secret_key params. Now I am getting, `expected *mut u32, found *mut u8`.

Comment: That's because `std::ffi:c_uint` is the wrong answer. It's the equivalent for `unsigned int` in C, which is in most systems a `u32`. `u8` is indeed the proper equivalent for `uint8_t`, your original code was already correct in that regard.